# How do i prevent android device from sharing screen from USB?

Tags: android, android-studio

**FLAG_SECURE** prevents taking screen pictures and screen mirroring. But **FLAG_SECURE** doesn't prevent screen sharing over USB. I do screen sharing with **scrcpy** program. **DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED** is not a sufficient solution. How can I prevent **scrcpy** from grabbing my screen? I have to do this on Android Studio.

Comment: Given that one can always take a photo of the screen, there is little value in getting this super tight.

Comment: Required for security evaluation

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, even after tried with **FLAG_SECURE** but the best option is to check if developer option is eneble or not.

Please follow below solution to check if developer option is turned on or not.

```
  public static int devOptions(Context context) {
    int devOptions = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 0);
    return devOptions;
}
```

if response is 1 then developer option is turned on and you can ask user to turned off first.

Happy Coding...